# FFMPEG C++ Non monotonically increasing dts to muxer

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I have two inputs:

- Stream with audio and video
- Stream with only video

I want to generate an ouput stream mixing Audio from the first stream and Video from the second stream.

But when i generate the output it says i am non monotonically increasing dts to muxer. I think im messing up with the dts.
Please help!!

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

//Linux...
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
#include <libavutil/time.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    AVOutputFormat* ofmt = NULL;
    //Input AVFormatContext and Output AVFormatContext
    AVFormatContext *audio_video_ifmt_ctx = NULL,
                    * only_video_ifmt_ctx = NULL,
                    * ofmt_ctx = NULL;

    AVPacket audio_video_pkt, only_video_pkt;
    const char *audio_video_in_filename, * only_video_in_filename,  * out_filename;
    int ret, i;
    int audio_video_audioindex = -1;
    int audio_video_videoindex = -1;
    int only_video_videoindex = -1;
    int audio_video_dataindex = -1;
    int only_video_dataindex = -1;


    int audio_video_frame_index = 0, only_video_frame_index = 0;
    audio_video_in_filename = "rtmp://localhost/live/STREAM_NAME.flv";
    only_video_in_filename = "rtmp://localhost/live/STREAM_NAME2.flv";
    out_filename = "rtmp://localhost/live/STREAM_NAME3.flv";
    //Network
    avformat_network_init();

    //Input ONLY VIDEO
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&only_video_ifmt_ctx, only_video_in_filename, 0, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("Could not open audio and video input file.");
        return 0;
    }
    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(only_video_ifmt_ctx, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("Failed to retrieve audio and video input stream information");
        return 0;
    }
    //Input AUDIO AND VIDEO
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&audio_video_ifmt_ctx, audio_video_in_filename, 0, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("Could not open only video input file.");
        return 0;
    }
    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(audio_video_ifmt_ctx, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("Failed to retrieve only video input stream information");
        return 0;
    }
    //Search audio_video stream index
    for (i = 0; i < audio_video_ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (audio_video_ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            audio_video_videoindex = i;
        }
        if (audio_video_ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            audio_video_audioindex = i;
        }
        if (audio_video_ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_DATA) {
            audio_video_dataindex = i;
        }
    }

    //Search only_video stream index
    for (i = 0; i < only_video_ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (only_video_ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            only_video_videoindex = i;
        }
        else if(audio_video_ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_DATA) {
            only_video_dataindex = i;
        }
    }

    av_dump_format(audio_video_ifmt_ctx, 0, audio_video_in_filename, 0);
    av_dump_format(only_video_ifmt_ctx, 0, only_video_in_filename, 0);

    //Allocate output stream context
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, out_filename); //RTMP
    if (!ofmt_ctx) {
        printf("Could not create output context\n");
        ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        return 0;
    }
    ofmt = ofmt_ctx->oformat;

    //Create Output Data and Audio Stream
    for (i = 0; i < audio_video_ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        AVStream* video_in_stream;
        //Create output AVStream according to input AVStream
        if (i == audio_video_dataindex) {
            video_in_stream = audio_video_ifmt_ctx->streams[audio_video_dataindex];
        }
        else if (i == audio_video_audioindex) {
            video_in_stream = audio_video_ifmt_ctx->streams[audio_video_audioindex];
        }
        else {
            video_in_stream = NULL;
            continue;
        }


        //AVStream *out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, in_stream->codec->codec);
        AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_decoder(video_in_stream->codecpar->codec_id);
        AVStream* out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, codec);

        if (!out_stream) {
            printf("Failed allocating output stream\n");
            ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
            return 0;
        }

        AVCodecContext* p_codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
        ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(p_codec_ctx, video_in_stream->codecpar);

        //Copy the settings of AVCodecContext
        if (ret < 0) {
            printf("Failed to copy context from input to output stream codec context\n");
            return 0;
        }
        p_codec_ctx->codec_tag = 0;
        if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
            p_codec_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
        ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(out_stream->codecpar, p_codec_ctx);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "eno:[%d] error to paramters codec paramter \n", ret);
        }
    }
    
    //Create Output Video Stream
    for (i = 0; i < only_video_ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        AVStream* video_in_stream;
        //Create output AVStream according to input AVStream
        if (i == only_video_dataindex) {
            continue;
            video_in_stream = only_video_ifmt_ctx->streams[only_video_dataindex];
        }
        else if (i == only_video_videoindex) {
            video_in_stream = only_video_ifmt_ctx->streams[only_video_videoindex];
        }
        else {
            video_in_stream = NULL;
            continue;
        }


        //AVStream *out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, in_stream->codec->codec);
        AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_decoder(video_in_stream->codecpar->codec_id);
        AVStream* out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, codec);

        if (!out_stream) {
            printf("Failed allocating output stream\n");
            ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
            return 0;
        }

        AVCodecContext* p_codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
        ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(p_codec_ctx, video_in_stream->codecpar);

        //Copy the settings of AVCodecContext
        if (ret < 0) {
            printf("Failed to copy context from input to output stream codec context\n");
            return 0;
        }
        p_codec_ctx->codec_tag = 0;
        if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
            p_codec_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
        ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(out_stream->codecpar, p_codec_ctx);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "eno:[%d] error to paramters codec paramter \n", ret);
        }
    }

    
   
    //Dump Format------------------
    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, out_filename, 1);
    //Open output URL
    if (!(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, out_filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            printf("Could not open output URL '%s'", out_filename);
            goto end;
        }
    }
    //Write output file header
    ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        printf("Error occurred when opening output URL\n");
        goto end;
    }
    //Pull stream
    while (1)
    {

        AVStream  *audio_video_in_stream, * only_video_in_stream, * out_stream;
        ret = av_read_frame(audio_video_ifmt_ctx, &audio_video_pkt);
        ret = av_read_frame(only_video_ifmt_ctx, &only_video_pkt);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;

        audio_video_in_stream = audio_video_ifmt_ctx->streams[audio_video_pkt.stream_index];
        only_video_in_stream = only_video_ifmt_ctx->streams[only_video_pkt.stream_index];
       
        out_stream = NULL;

        ///// TREAT AUDIO PACKETS /////

        if (audio_video_pkt.stream_index == audio_video_dataindex) {
            out_stream = ofmt_ctx->streams[0];
        }
        if (audio_video_pkt.stream_index == audio_video_audioindex) {
            out_stream = ofmt_ctx->streams[1];
        }
       
       
        //Convert PTS/DTS
        if (out_stream != NULL) {
            audio_video_pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(audio_video_pkt.pts, audio_video_in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
            audio_video_pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(audio_video_pkt.dts, audio_video_in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
            audio_video_pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(audio_video_pkt.duration, audio_video_in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
            audio_video_pkt.pos = -1;

           
        }
        //Writing audio stream
        if (out_stream != NULL) {
            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &audio_video_pkt);
        }
  
        ///// TREAT VIDEO PACKETS /////

        if (only_video_pkt.stream_index == only_video_videoindex) {
            out_stream = ofmt_ctx->streams[2];
        }

        //Convert PTS/DTS
        if (out_stream != NULL) {
            only_video_pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(only_video_pkt.pts, only_video_in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
            only_video_pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(only_video_pkt.dts, only_video_in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
            only_video_pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(only_video_pkt.duration, only_video_in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
            only_video_pkt.pos = -1;
        }
        //Writing video
        if (out_stream != NULL) {
            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &only_video_pkt);
        }
        //Desreferenciamos el paquete
        av_packet_unref(&audio_video_pkt);
        av_packet_unref(&only_video_pkt);

        if (ret < 0) {
            printf("Error muxing packet\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    //Write file trailer
    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
end:
    avformat_close_input(&audio_video_ifmt_ctx);
    avformat_close_input(&only_video_ifmt_ctx);

    /* close output */
    if (ofmt_ctx && !(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        avio_close(ofmt_ctx->pb);
    avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);
    if (ret < 0 && ret != AVERROR_EOF) {
        printf("Error occurred.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://localhost/live/STREAM_NAME.flv':
  Metadata:
    fileSize        : 0
    audiochannels   : 2
    2.1             : false
    3.1             : false
    4.0             : false
    4.1             : false
    5.1             : false
    7.1             : false
    encoder         : obs-output module (libobs version 25.0.4)
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 2910.332000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Data: none
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 163 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 2560 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://localhost/live/STREAM_NAME2.flv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.65.101
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 2726.365000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Data: none
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 52 fps, 52 tbr, 1k tbn, 104 tbc
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://localhost/live/STREAM_NAME3.flv':
    Stream #0:0: Data: none
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 163 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31
[flv @ 0000014F2CDB9500] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 1: 2910332 >= 2726346
Error muxing packet
[flv @ 0000014F2CDB9500] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0000014F2CDB9500] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
Error occurred.
```

Comment: Same here. Have you found a solution?

Comment: no, sorry... If you happen to find a solution please let me know. I quit this project because i couldn't solve it.